# Find first instance of character, then stop at space?

Tags: php, regex

I think I need to use some kind of regex but struggling...

I have a string e.g.

```
the cat sat on the mat and $10 was all it cost
```

I want to return

```
$10
```

And is there a universal name for currency codes so I could return £10 if it was

```
the cat sat on the mat and £10 was all it cost
```

Or a way to add more characters to the expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
/(\$.*?) /
```

(note there is a space after the closing parenthesis)

If you want to add more symbols, then use brackets:

```
$str = 'the cat sat on the mat and £10 was all it cost';
$matches = array();
preg_match( '/([\$£].*?) /', $str, $matches );
```

This will work if the currency symbol precedes the value, and if there is a space following the value. You might want to check for more general cases, such as the value being at the end of a sentence with no trailing space etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match all currency codes, use the following regex:

```
/\p{Sc}\d+(\.\d+)?\b/u
```

**explanation:**

```
/           # regex delimiter
  \p{Sc}    # a currency symbol
  \d+       # 1 or more digit
  (\.\d+)?  # optionally followed by a dot and one or more digit
  \b        # word boundary
/           # regex delimiter
u           # unicode
```

Have a look at [this site](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/) to see the meaning of `\p{Sc}` (Currency Symbol)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'the cat sat on the mat and $10 was all it cost';
$found = preg_match_all('/[$£]\d*/',$string,$results);
if ($found)
    var_dump($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may works for you

```
$string = "the cat sat on the mat and $10 was all it cost";
preg_match("/ ([\$£\]{1})([0-9]+)/", $string, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
```